# Using landscape from command line

Tags: landscape

Is there any doc for managing landscape using the command line? For example, how can I test a ping from my client machine?

Comment: is there anyone who can answer? or no one uses landscape as CM tool?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that what you are asking for is how to manage Landscape server via CLI. Therefore I would like to point you to User Guide located here https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/user-guide/
This will be a good start.

With regards to CLI tools you would need to pick which one do you feel most comfortable with/ your preference:
https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/

And just to get you started there are 3 ways of using this API:

**command-line client**: easy to use, shell-script friendly

**Python module**: more powerful, recommended if you want to drive the API via Python

**low-level HTTP requests:** in the case you want to know what is going on, or write a client for some other language

My personal favourite is the command line client. Once you install landscape-api and source your keys ( you can find, generate and refresh them from Landscape server GUI, just click on your name when you are logged in) as per https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/api-client-package.html
you can get all the information from your Landscape server and attached machines:

example:

```
$ landscape-api get-computers | grep host
  u'hostname': u'xxx.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com',
  u'hostname': u'xxx.eu-west-2.compute.internal',
  u'hostname': u'laptop',

$ landscape-api get-computers | grep ping
  u'last_ping_time': u'2018-12-05T16:45:39Z',
  u'last_ping_time': u'2018-12-05T16:45:39Z',
  u'last_ping_time': u'2018-12-05T15:24:20Z',
```

I am grepping here just to show you example as full output for even 3 machines is quite big especially if you run it with additional switches:

```
$ landscape-api get-computers --with-hardware
```

or

```
$ landscape-api get-computers --with-hardware --json
```

Then you can additionally parse that with jq for additional text manipulation

Hope this will help.